# AWX dynamic inventory duplicate get requests

Tags: python, ansible, inventory, ansible-tower

I'm working on AWX and I wrote a custom script to build an inventory. The script simply makes a GET request to an API to retrieve a list of machines with the status "ON".

When this script is launched on AWX, I saw multiple GET requests to the API (actually one per host) instead of only one. I don't know where the problem can come from.

Here is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import json
headers = {
    "Authorization": "xxx"
}
url = 'https://xxxxx.com/api/ppd/machineson'
r = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.text)
print({"XPC_PPD": {'hosts': data["objects"]}})
```

An example of the output: 
It takes 11.0s to import 20 hosts, 20 GET requests instead of one:

[image: OUTPUT CAPTURE]

Answer (score 0):

I found out it is a published feature of Ansible inventory scripts that will re-call the script once for every host if it does not provide the hostvars dict nested under the _meta dict. My script did not do this, so it is extremely likely that's what's happening. It's also likely that it nests the entire inventory contents under hostvars for every one of your hosts, because the contract it is assuming is that passing the --host option to your script will tell the script to give variables for that host.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#inventory-script-conventions

The schema below has to be respected:

```
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {}
  },
  "all": {
    "children": [
      "ungrouped"
    ]
  },
  "ungrouped": {
    "children": [
   ]
 }
}
```